# Auto-login via sign in with Google without SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

I've tried to implement silent sign-in as [mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient))

I've tried to restrict other domain login via regex, I don't know if any other method is out there, I've seen the 'hd' parameter in Firebase login, but implementation was unsuccessful.

Edit 1: Fixed code, now the silent sign-in doesn't work. Code is redundant, also GoogleApiClient is deprecate.

I've seen answers with SharedPreferences to save login token, but is it safe to save token?

I've followed the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

MainActivity.java

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            silentLogin();
        }

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

       //Show sign-in and sign-out buttons

    public void silentLogin() {
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (pendingResult != null) {
            handleGooglePendingResult(pendingResult);
        } else {
            signIn();
        }
    }
        private void handleGooglePendingResult(OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult) {
        if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
            GoogleSignInResult signInResult = pendingResult.get();
            onSilentSignInCompleted(signInResult);
        } else {
            pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult signInResult) {
                    onSilentSignInCompleted(signInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onSilentSignInCompleted(GoogleSignInResult signInResult) {
        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = signInResult.getSignInAccount();
        if (signInAccount != null) {
            //Show sign out button
        }
        else {
            signIn();
        }
    }

    private void signIn(){
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask){
        try{
            GoogleSignInAccount acc = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            FirebaseGoogleAuth(acc);
        }
        catch (ApiException e){
            //Show error
            FirebaseGoogleAuth(null);
        }
    }

    private void FirebaseGoogleAuth(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        if (acct != null) {
            AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            // Auth failed
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser fUser){
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
        if(account !=  null){
            String personName = account.getDisplayName();
            String personEmail = account.getEmail();

            if (personEmail != null) {
                if(personEmail.endsWith("gmail.com"))
                {
                    //Show details
                }
                    else
                    {
                        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login with gmail account only",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Show sign in button again
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Connection failed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **mAuth** is null because it's defined after you are doing the process with it.

`mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` line should be before that condition.

Do it as below:

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        silentLogin();
    }
```

It will work for sure.

## Edited:

What I have done in my project:

```
 final GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MyActivity.this);

 if (account != null) {
    gotoNextActivity();
 } else {
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't invoke silentlogin method, it's not working, I can't find a way how can I do auto-login which was the main problem, user has to still click sign-in again when user exits and opens the app again, I've edited the code as per your suggestion

Comment: So error gone? Now You should clear data, clear login detail from firebase and check again.

Comment: Tried, it tells to sign in after the app is closed, it can't access previous firebase instance or the the firebase token is lost, when the user clicks to sign in, no issues, it saves last login details, and doesn't ask user to select account, I was trying to automate it

Comment: @SujitMaiti Check another method as I have done previously.

Comment: I got the gotoNextActivity must be a intent activity, but what mBinding refers to?

Comment: Its simple your `button` click listener. I have used DataBinding so mBinding was there. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the previous answer and reading a few documentations, I've come to conclusion as I've implemented the above in the following manner:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                        .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);

        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {

        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            if(Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseUser.getEmail()).endsWith("gmail.com"))
            {
               //Display details of user
            }
            else
            {
                //Sign out
                mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();
                updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login with gmail address only!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            // Show sign in button
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> accountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleGoogleSignIn(accountTask);
        }
    }

    private void handleGoogleSignIn(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> accountTask) {

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = accountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) {
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }
        }
}

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // Show error
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

If there's a better approach, please comment.

Documentation referred:

[1: Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

[2: Firebase Google Sign In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)